# Editing harvested metadata records without data loss during next run in GeoNetwork?

Tags: geonetwork

I want to edit harvested metadata records without losing data during the next run in GeoNetwork 2.10.4 because whenever I am updating keywords it gets lost next day.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Would you be able to provide a more detailed description of the workflow that you are currently using to edit harvested metadata records, please?  Also, include how you establish that the metadata is present before that work is done, and absent afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Geonetwork 2.10.4, but in Geonetwork 3, there is setting:

> Allow editing on harvested records: Enables/Disables editing of harvested records in the catalogue. By default, harvested records cannot be edited.

Maybe better solution for old Geonetwork:

> Another option would be to assign the harvested records to the local catalog and then modify them.

But in both cases harvested data will stop updating.